# Missing int in nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

The following code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    System.out.println();
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(j);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Removing in the brace:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    System.out.println();
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(j);
}
```

produces:

```
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
```

I can understand that the nested for loop is iterating through the `" "` and printing them, then just printing one `j`, but I don't understand what happens to `j = 1`.

Comment: its a basic fundamental of any programming language.that if you remove curly braces before a loop..only one statement after that will gonna execute.!

Comment: run in http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/# for a visual of what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For-loop without brace. Code you mentioned below:

```
 for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(j);
```

It is equal to the following code:

```
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(j);
```

That's the problem, have a try and go ahead.

You can change it as follows:

```
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(j);
        }
```

The output will be expecte, like:

```
  1
  1 2
  1 2 3
  1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

THe first time it goes through your for loop

1. it sets j = 1, checks j <= i
2. prints out the space
3. increments j, checks j < = i *this fails because i = 1 and j = 2*
4. exits the loop, and prints j and j = 2

Comment: +1 point is if you do not use braces it only the adjacent line will come under loop

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out

```
System.out.println();
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(j);
```

The `j` is incremented `j++` before being printed, as the loop has gone through an iteration befoe arriving at the `System.out.print(j);`

Comment: +1 concisely if you do not use braces it only the adjacent line will come under loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since it only executes one statement, the value of `j` when it gets printed is one greater than the upper bound of your inner loop (2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but the for-loop won't end until `j > i` in your code, and since `i` is 1-5, `j` will be printed as 2-6, which are the values needed to fail the `j <= i` condition.